# Devexpress ASPxCallback client side e.Result undefined

Tags: c#, devexpress, client-side

I call `cb.PerformCallback();` it looks working correctly but I can not get the `e.result`.
it alerts "undefined".

I can both see "started" and "ended" alerts.

```
ASPxCallback cb = new ASPxCallback(); 
cb.ID = cb.ClientInstanceName = "cb";
cb.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = @"function (s,e) { alert('started'); alert(e.result); }";
cb.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = @"function (s,e) { alert('ended'); alert(e.result); }";
```

how can I get e.result?

Comment: what dx version you use?

Comment: F12 dev toolbar @ie9 should allow you to step through, put a breakpoint and analyze "e" at runtime so you can see what's actually in there

Comment: I am using the latest demo in chrome.if I debug i see 'e' is undefined...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxCallbackScriptsASPxClientCallback_CallbackCompletetopic

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesScriptsASPxClientBeginCallbackEventArgsMembersTopicAll

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesScriptsASPxClientEndCallbackEventArgsMembersTopicAll

Comment: According to documentation EndCallback and BeginCallback don't have parameter result. CallbackComplete event has.

Answer (score 4):

Handle the **ASPxClientCallback.CallbackComplete** event instead and use the **e.result** property (take attention to the character case):

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/Callback/Example.aspx